# How to convert varchar to datetime in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I am trying to populate the data from `table1` to `table2`, both have the same number of columns.

All the columns in `table1` are of type `varchar`. The columns in `table2` could be `varchar`, `int` or `datetime`, etc.

My question is how to do the conversion during the populating?

This is a sample query that I wrote. I miss the part to do the conversion. Also the format of my `datetime` is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

```
insert into table2
    select s.acty_id, s.notes_datetime, s.notes_data
    from table1 t right join table2 s 
    on (t.acty_id =s.acty_id and t.notes_datetime =s.notes_datetime)
    where t.acty_id is null
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will use a [`CAST()` or `CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your field:

```
Declare @dt varchar(20)
set @dt = '08-12-2012 10:15:10'
select convert(datetime, @dt, 101)
```

For your query you would do the following:

```
insert into table2
select s.acty_id, s.notes_datetime, s.notes_data
from table1 t 
right join table2 s 
    on t.acty_id =s.acty_id 
    and convert(datetime, t.notes_datetime, 101) = s.notes_datetime
where t.acty_id is null
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit, but a couple of things: table1 is where the varchar exists, not table2, and you need to do a *safe* cast so you should use convert with a style that matches the string format (m/d/y) so that you don't end up with problems on a non-US English system or with different session settings.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I caught the varchar in table1 and edited it to correct that mistake.  Too many table1, table2's.  You are right about the correct, conversion format too...as always

Comment: I am not sure I understand the first part. can you explain? will this work? insert into table2
    select s.acty_id, convert(datetime, s.notes_datetime, s.notes_data, 101), s.notes_data from table1 t 
    right join table2 s 
     on t.acty_id =s.acty_id 
     and convert(datetime, t.notes_datetime, 101) = s.notes_datetime
    where t.acty_id is null

Comment: It seems work. But if I put 12/23/2012 12:00:01 (varchar), it will convert to 2012-12-31 12:00:01.000 (datetime). I used convert(datetime, colname, 101). what should I do to keep the value as 12/23/2012 12:00:01 as a datetime type?

Comment: @GaolaiPeng it is working for me, see this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2fec5/1

Answer (score 5):

The right answer is to correct table1 so that it is using the right data types. In the meantime, assuming you need to match both date and time, you can try this:

```
and CONVERT(DATETIME, t.notes_datetime, 101) = s.notes_datetime
```