# How to embed a variable in a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the following SQL in SEDE (StackExchange Data Explorer).
This `SQL` can specify the date and time for `CreationDate`, and the default value uses the value of `@MonthsAgo` variable.

This works fine if you enter a date and time, but you get the following error with the `@MonthsAgo` variable:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1187086/1459772

```
declare @MonthsAgo date = cast(dateadd(month, -2, getdate()) as date)
declare @since date = ##SinceDate:string?@MonthsAgo##

select vote.PostId, post.Score, post.CreationDate from votes vote
  inner join posts post on post.Id = vote.PostId
where post.CreationDate >= @since and Tags like '%java%'
order by post.Score desc
```

How can I search using this variable?

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

The `##SinceDate:string?@MonthsAgo##` is pseudocode and It isn't running in SQL Server.

StackExchange Data Explorer uses `##xxx##` format to replace with Parameters that you enter on Parameter Section.

In a nutshell, If you want to convert `NVarChar` or `Varchar` to `DateTime` (or `Date`) Type :

```
Declare @since varchar(20)
set @since = '08-12-2012 10:15:10'
select convert(datetime, @since , 101)
```

Orginal Source : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099059/how-to-convert-varchar-to-datetime-in-t-sql)

Comment: Where does that conversion apply?
I tried to convert the two input values to strings and convert them to DATETIME later, but that is [caused same error](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1187095).

Comment: Parameters will replace on the server when you hit the Run Query key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@MonthsAgo` parameter at the query without specifying a type. If you use any type as a string, SEDE treats it like a string, not a parameter name.

```
declare @MonthsAgo date = cast(dateadd(month, -2, getdate()) as date)

select vote.PostId, post.Score, post.CreationDate from votes vote
  inner join posts post on post.Id = vote.PostId
  where post.CreationDate >= ##SinceDate?@MonthsAgo## and Tags like '%java%'
order by post.Score desc
```

Comment: However, that query does not return posts dated after 2019-12-31 when you specify `2019-12-31`. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1187659/1460544/?SinceDate=2019-12-31